# Change Link href Based on Viewport (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm in a special scenario where I need to change the `href` of an `<a>` that is inside a `<li>`, if the `<li>` has a child `<ul>`, and if the viewport is sub 480px.

I know very little about writing javascript, but I'm thinking that this is how the logic would work:

1. Is the viewport equal to or lesser than 480px?
2. If so, find any `<li>`'s directly inside `<nav id="navigation1">`'s top-level `<ul>`.
3. From what #2 returns, find any that also contain a child `<a>`.
4. From what #3 returns, find any that also contain a child `<ul>`.
5. From what #4 returns, change the `href` value of the `<a>` in the top `<li>`'s to ''#navigation1``.

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation1" class="navigation" style="height:auto; z-index:1; overflow:visible">
    <ul class="f-fp f-lp" id="fwNav1">
        <li class="fwNavItem"><a href="change-this-link.html"><span class="Navigation">About</span></a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li class="fwFirstChild fwNavItem"><a href="#"><span class="Navigation">About Me</span></a></li>
                <li class="fwNavItem"><a href="#"><span class="Navigation">About You</span></a></li>
                <li class="fwLastChild fwNavItem"><a href="#"><span class="Navigation">About We</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="fwNavItem"><a href="change-this-link.html"><span class="Navigation">Services</span></a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li class="fwFirstChild fwNavItem"><a href="#"><span class="Navigation">What Me Do</span></a></li>
                <li class="fwLastChild fwNavItem"><a href="#"><span class="Navigation">What You Do</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

(I know, not the prettiest HTML, but it's created by a WYSIWYG and I have no control over it. Sorry.)

The solution must be in vanilla javascript, no jQuery please.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the type of thing jQuery excels at. Why would you not want to use it?

Comment: @warpedspeed I know. However, this must not cause conflicts with other JS libraries.

Comment: What other js libraries might it conflict with?  That information might allow for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @jandjorgensen: This is going into a template that might be used with either jQuery or Prototype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 480) { // note 1
    var links = document.querySelectorAll("#navigation1 > ul > li > a");
    var link;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        link = links[i];
        if (link.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul").length > 0) // note 2
            link.href = "#navigation1";
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** `window.innerWidth` doesn't exist in IE8- (you didn't specify your browser requirements). Since `undefined < 480` is false,
this just means the code won't be run there, which is probably fine. Also you may want to change to `<= 480` depending on what you want; your question is contradictory in that regard.

**Note 2:** This is not 100% your point 4.; rather, it checks that there is any *descendant* `<ul>`, not necessarily a child. This seems fine from your HTML,
but if it's not, then you need an extra check (either iterate through the direct children of `link.parentElement` and check for a `<ul>`,
or check the results of `getElementsByTagName()` for one whose `parentElement` is identical to `link.parentElement`. Unfortunately,
there's no standard DOM method to filter direct childs of a given element by some property).

You should also keep in mind that this only runs once, so a browser resize (or phone orientation change) may change the width but not cause the links to be updated. This is an issue if the requirement to change the links is e.g. related to responsive CSS (i.e. media queries), because the CSS will change according to the new width.